# How to reset keyboard driver?

Tags: keyboard, virtual-consoles

I have a KVM switch sharing my USB keyboard between Linux and Windows systems. If the switch is set to the Linux box when it boots up then the keyboard works fine. If I switch away to the Windows box the keyboard still works fine, but if I switch back to Linux I start getting missed and repeated keystrokes, making it almost unusable. This is on a virtual terminal and the problem carries across to the other vts as well.

Is there some way that I can reset the keyboard or its driver without having to reboot?

I'm running an ancient Fedora Core 8 distro, if that matters.

Thanks.

Comment: This question really should state whether this is USB or PS/2.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the X server and then exiting it seems to fix the problem. A bit heavy-handed, but better than rebooting.